# All fields are showing in one column when exporting mysqli data to excel using php

Tags: php, excel, mysqli

I have written a simple php script for download excel file which contain some MySQLI data fetching by a MySQLI query, it was working fine when I was using English data but when I used utf 8 language such as Arabic, it shows all the data in one column in the excel file,

here is the code, any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($conn, 'test_db');
mysqli_query($conn, "set names 'utf8'");
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');

$sql = "SELECT `user_name`,`user_q1`,`user_q2`,
                `user_q3`,`user_q4`,`user_q5` 
        FROM    `usertable`";

$setRec = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$columnHeader = '';
$columnHeader = "الاسم" . "\t" . "الاجابة 1" . "\t" . "الاجابة 2" . "\t". "الاجابة 3" . "\t". "الاجابة 4" . "\t". "الاجابة 5" . "\t";

$setData = '';
while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_row($setRec)) {
    $rowData = '';
    foreach ($rec as $value) {
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        $rowData .= $value;
    }
    $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=User_Detail.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Use [`fputcsv`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) instead. Why are you using `$value` for formatting and then appending the value to `$rowData`? It's just a waste of resources.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.